# Why does ifelse not process complex test conditions (difference between && / & and || / |)?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

So suppose I have the following:

```
library(zoo)
v <- read.zoo(data.frame(dt=as.Date('2011-01-01')+0:9, a=1:10, b=11:20, c=21:30), index.column = "dt")
```

Why does this work:

```
ifelse(v$a > 5, 1, 0)
```

and this DOESN'T work:

```
ifelse(v$a > 5 && v$a < 8, 1, 0)
```

Comment: becauuse `&&` returns a single TRUE/FALSE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ifelse` needs all arguments to be of same length. According to `?ifelse`

> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.

ie. if one of the argument is > 1, and others are 1 length, it recycles the other arguments to make the lengths same.  In the second case, all the arguments are of length 1 as according to `?"&&"

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

```
v$a > 5 && v$a < 8 
#[1] FALSE  # length 1
```

while

```
v$a > 5 & v$a < 8
#2011-01-01 2011-01-02 2011-01-03 2011-01-04 2011-01-05 2011-01-06 2011-01-07 2011-01-08 2011-01-09 2011-01-10 
#     FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE       TRUE       TRUE      FALSE      FALSE      FALSE
```

So, there is no recycling here.  Instead, if we use `&` only, then it would give the expected output

```
ifelse(v$a > 5 & v$a < 8, 1, 0)
```

---

Also, note that `as.integer` coerces the `TRUE/FALSE` to binary `1/0`.  So, there is no need for `ifelse` here

```
as.integer(v$a > 5)
```

Or

```
as.integer(v$a > 5 & v$a < 8)
```

Comment: What if you mix them accidentally? i.e. `as.integer((v$a > 5 & v$a > 8) || v$a == 4)`